# rsync-style solution on Windows that can be deployed silently?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, rsync

I'm building a (for now pretty minimal) network sync system for some of our users, involving a samba server on one end and an rsync cron job which is "installed" for OSX or Linux clients by running a simple bash script linked from our intranet.

I need to do the same thing for Windows clients. I know there are several rsync implementations on Windows (I used cwRsync ages ago), but are there any (off the top of your head) that I can silently pass a config to during install? As it is, I guess I'm going to have to write a crappy old batchfile to interface with Windows Task Scheduler, but I'd at least like for clients installing this to not have to input any more than their username and password.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with

- [RichCopy](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/33971726-eeb7-4452-bebf-02ed6518743e/)
- [RoboCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Cygwin `rsync.exe`](http://cygwin.com/)

All using scheduled tasks.

RichCopy (and maybe robocopy) have options to save config files from the GUI. All worked well for me from a batch file.

All three have restartable/incremental modes. Most are highly aware of specific features think

- NTFS encryption
- NTFS compression
- permissions (ACLs)
- alternate NTFS streams
- junctions/reparse points
- hardlinks/symlinks

etc.